# Sound from headphones but not from speakers in Alienware 14

Tags: sound

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 in my Alienware 14 (july-2013) laptop.

Apparently there is no sound from speakers, however when I connect headphones sound is perfect through them.

I've tried to purge-remove-reinstall alsa drivers and pulseaudio, and still no sound. I even tried some solution I found through this site related to adding the following:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=alienware
```

to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` (I also tried with generic, Intel, dell and ref) and no luck whatsoever. I also tried updating to the latest kernel (3.12) and still without sound coming out from the speakers. Volume controls are all un-muted, I checked it as well.

Any suggestion?

This is the output for the command `aplay -l`

```
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC668 Analog [ALC668 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to solve it somehow. I added this two lines to `alsa-base.conf` (and also enabling `auto-mute` in `alsa-mixer`):

```
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m4-1 enable_msi=1
```

After rebooting, sound is working from the speakers.