# no sound in ubuntu 18.04 LTS after laptop restart on getting freezed

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

i am usiNg `ubuntu 18.04 LTS` sound was working fine till yesterday my laptop got hanged and i restarted it from there i have no sound in ubuntu, i have windows 10 insattled as well on my laptop sound is working fine there so there is no hardware issues. I have tried a bunch of solutions given on the internet but no luck 
here is what i have done so far

tried all the solutions given [here](https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/)

```
inxi -SMA
```

gives

```
System:    Host: my-Inspiron-7773 Kernel: 4.15.0-99-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: Dell product: Inspiron 7773 serial: N/A
           Mobo: Dell model: 0R58C3 v: A00 serial: N/A UEFI: Dell v: 1.9.0 date: 06/12/2018
Audio:     Card Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel Sound: ALSA v: k4.15.0-99-generic
```

here is my audio setting 
[image]

i have tried `alsamixer` speakers are on 100% tested both with default and `HDA Intel PCH`
here is my settings 
[image]
then

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

gives

```
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-soc-skl snd-soc-skl-ipc snd-hda-ext-core snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-soc-sst-dsp snd-soc-sst-ipc snd-soc-acpi snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-soc-skl snd-soc-skl-ipc snd-hda-ext-core snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-soc-sst-dsp snd-soc-sst-ipc snd-soc-acpi snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer.
```

and run these commands as well

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base
sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

rebooted the system 
 also updated the kernel using this [link](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-update-kernel-ubuntu)

```
uname -r
```

gives `4.15.0-99-generic`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

kernel version remains the same after that (4.15.0-99-generic
)

the command `pulseaudio --start`
gives

```
 N: [pulseaudio] main.c: User-configured server at {d31e5be658484174a49d9c408bcecf46}unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native, which appears to be local. Probing deeper.

sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
pavucontrol
```

and its configurations is set to

```
analog stereo duplex
```

and switched to

```
Analog stereo output
```

[image]
all the above solutions and the one given in the first link i mentioned did not worked for me
took help from these links NOTHING WORKED :( 
[No audio on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029502/no-audio-on-ubuntu-18-04)
[No sound in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046114/no-sound-in-ubuntu-18-04)
[Ubuntu 18.04 sound suddenly stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134282/ubuntu-18-04-sound-suddenly-stopped-working)

Comment: Can you try https://askubuntu.com/questions/390835/sound-from-headphones-but-not-from-speakers-in-alienware-14

Comment: tried nothing worked

Comment: `ps -ef | grep pulse` gives?

Comment: gdm       2835  2034  0 12:10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no
sara      3676     1  0 12:10 ?        00:00:25 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
sara     10474  8537  0 12:54 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto pulse

Comment: you are not alone with this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/584151/sound-no-longer-works-after-updating-linux-mint-and-ive-lost-the-tray-icon-wha  and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1875916

Comment: yes the problem was in the latest kernel  4.15.0-99-generic. ,booted from the previous kernel version fixed the issue which is 4.15.0-96-generic thank you so much